# perl mojolicious mango driver: utf-8 characters not written correctly into mongodb

Tags: mongodb, perl, mojolicious

Anybody with mojolicious mango(https://metacpan.org/pod/Mango) knowledge can tell me how do you insert utf-8 characters into mongodb. 
Or maybe is this missing feature of the mango?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and add a bit more detail? As it stands, the question is very vague and more suited for an open discussion forum than for the q&a format we do here at SO. Have you tried inserting those chars? How did you do that? Please provide a [mcve] so we can play around in order to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mango has no issue with utf8 strings. I use them all the time. Your problem must lie elsewhere.

In the following example, `Mojo::Base` implicitly imports the `utf8` pragma, which tells perl to treat all strings in the source code as utf8. Also, before printing text to the console, i tell perl to use the utf8 IO layer on `stdout`, otherwise it won't print correctly. Note that you could use the `:raw` IO layer instead and it would work just as well.

```
use Mojo::Base -strict;
use Mango;

sub mango { state $m = Mango->new }
sub coll  { mango->db('test')->collection('utf8') }

my $text = "utf8 is not so hard ";

my $oid = coll->insert({ text => $text });
my $doc = coll->find_one($oid);
binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");
say $doc->{text};
```

Comment: Yes problem was elsewhere, sorry wrong assumption from my side... I had double utf-8 encoded string problem. Thanks for the answer.